# Cannot convert type of instance to type of interface where instance implements interface

Tags: c#, generics

Why Given the following classes

```
class ParentClass<T>{   }
class ChildClass : IInterface{  }
interface IInterface{   }
```

Do I get a compile time error 'Cannot convert type' when I try to convert from the type `ParentClass<ChildClass>` to `ParentClass<IInterface>`, with the below code.

```
var concreteGeneric = new ParentClass<ChildClass>();
var interfaceGeneric = (ParentClass<IInterface>)concreteClass;
```

Comment: @janhartmann Isn´t this obvious? Convert `MyClass<T>` to `MyClass<BaseInterface>` where `T : BaseInterface`?.

Comment: Just because two types, say `CC` and `II` have a particular inheritance or implementation relationship, that doesn't mean that `PC<CC>` and `PC<II>` have the *same* relationship. In fact, they have *no* such relationship.

Comment: In this context, for the following casting to work `(ParentClass<IInterface>)concreteClass`, it must be true that the type `ParentClass<ChildClass>` inherits from `ParentClass<IInterface>`. The latter is not the case, so the casting will fail. You have to provide more information to solve the problem.

Comment: @Candide I'm trying to provide a helper method for ParentClass when It's generic type is IInterface. eg `public static void HelperMethod(this ParentClass<IInterface> parentClass){}` So I can act on IInterfaces Members. This isn't working as I can't make the conversion. It sounds like what I'm trying to do isn't going to work and I need to rethink the problem.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). In C# it is supported only for interfaces (where with "for interfaces" I mean that the "external" type must be an interface, not the generic type, so a `IParentClass<>`)

Comment: @Norf in this case, you should probably create an interface which is implemented by `ParentClass` so that you can add your extension method to that interface instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is called covariance and (as @xanatos mentioned) it is only supported for interfaces.  If you add an interface to your ParentClass, you can do a conversion to `IParentClass<IInterface>` and get the functionality you are looking for.

```
class ParentClass<T> : IParentClass<T> where T : IInterface { }
class ChildClass : IInterface { }
interface IInterface { }
interface IParentClass<out T> where T : IInterface { }

public void TestMethodX()
{
    var concreteGeneric = new ParentClass<ChildClass>();
    var interfaceGeneric = (IParentClass<IInterface>)concreteGeneric;
}
```

Comment: To the OP: be aware that the `out` in `IParentClass<out T>` is **very** important.

Comment: Small nitpick: I think the `where` is necessary for the concrete declaration, but not for the interface one... anyways, not a biggie.  +1

Comment: @code4life I tried it that way and it didn't compile.  Good point to review.

Comment: You're right.  I was actually trying the reverse of what you described when it didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify precisely which interface extend T

```
class ParentClass<T> where T:IInterface {   }
```

Comment: This won't fix the issue. `ParentClass<IInterface> x = new ParentClass<ChildClass>()`; will still fail at run-time.

Comment: And if you specify like that : ParentClass<IInterface> interfaceGeneric = concreteClass;